# Removing duplicated subquery in pl/sql procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to simplify following procedure?

I want to remove duplication of WITH clause.

```
IF p_YN = 'Y' THEN
    OPEN p_cursor FOR
        WITH VIEW_A AS
        (
            [very long select statements]
        )
        SELECT COL_A, COL_B, SUM(COL_C), SUM(COL_D) FROM VIEW_A
        GROUP BY COL_A, COL_B;
ELSE
    OPEN p_cursor FOR
        WITH VIEW_A AS
        (
            [very long select statements]
        )
        SELECT COL_1, COL_2, SUM(COL_3), SUM(COL_4) FROM VIEW_A
        GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2;
END IF;
```

I considered UNON ALL.

```
WITH VIEW_A AS
(
    [very long select statements]
)
OPEN p_cursor FOR

SELECT COL_A, COL_B, SUM(COL_C), SUM(COL_D) FROM VIEW_A
GROUP BY COL_A, COL_B
WHERE p_YN = 'Y'

UNION ALL

SELECT COL_1, COL_2, SUM(COL_3), SUM(COL_4) FROM VIEW_A
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2
WHERE p_YN <> 'Y';
```

But this doesn't work because two statements have different columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `UNION ALL` can do what you need, maybe you can simply add same "fake" columns:

```
WITH VIEW_A AS
(
    [very long select statements]
)
OPEN p_cursor FOR

SELECT COL_A, COL_B, SUM(COL_C), SUM(COL_D), NULL AS COL_1, NULL AS COL_2, NULL AS COL_3, NULL AS COL_4
FROM VIEW_A
GROUP BY COL_A, COL_B
WHERE p_YN = 'Y'

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL AS COL_A, NULL AS COL_B, NULL AS COL_C, NULL AS COL_D, COL_1, COL_2, SUM(COL_3), SUM(COL_4) 
FROM VIEW_A
GROUP BY COL_1, COL_2
WHERE p_YN <> 'Y';
```

`NULL` should be changed in something else, depending on the types of  your columns; besides, this may work or not, depending on what you need to do with the opened cursor.